# Shopware: Store custom field for customer

Tags: shopware

I added this custom field to my customer and to the register form in `storefront/component/account/register.html.twig`:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="alumni" name="custom_kw_dau" value="1">
```

The field is type checkbox. It works fine in the backend but it is not filled during customer registration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to manually store it. Subscribe to event and add the field to `customFields` in the output like this:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{
    return [
        CustomerEvents::MAPPING_REGISTER_CUSTOMER => 'addCustomField'
    ];
}

public function addCustomField(DataMappingEvent $event): bool
{
    $inputData = $event->getInput();
    $outputData = $event->getOutput();

    $custom_field = (bool)$inputData->get('custom_kw_dau', false);
    $outputData['customFields'] = array('custom_kw_dau' => $custom_field);

    $event->setOutput($outputData);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you need to subscribe to the event - but I have done it like this instead of the above event, and it works fine as well.

```
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            CustomerRegisterEvent::class => 'onRegister',
            GuestCustomerRegisterEvent::class => 'onRegister'
        ];
    }


    public function onRegister(CustomerRegisterEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        if ($request) {
            $params = $request->request->all();
            $customer = $event->getCustomer();
            $data = [
                'id' => $customer->getId(),
                'customFields' => [
                    'your_field' => $params['your_field']
                ]
            ];

            $this->customerRepository->update([$data], $event->getContext());
        }
    }
```

But I think the answer above might be more suitable as it does not require any additional services.